# How do I change the direction (or side) of the footnote line?

Tags: lyx, footnotes, rules, hebrew

I saw those questions:

- [How can I change the footnote line (thickness, length)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21913/how-can-i-change-the-footnote-line-thickness-length)
- [Add indent to \footnoterule](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64479/add-indent-to-footnoterule)

But I don't find the answer there...
So I'll be glad if you will tell me what I need to put at the preamble (I'm using LyX) to move the footnote rule from the left side of the page to the right side of the page...

Thank you!!

And here is a file for example:

```
#LyX 2.2 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 508
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass heb-article
\begin_preamble
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Simple CLM}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language hebrew
\language_package default
\inputencoding cp1255
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts true
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\pdf_bookmarks true
\pdf_bookmarksnumbered false
\pdf_bookmarksopen false
\pdf_bookmarksopenlevel 1
\pdf_breaklinks false
\pdf_pdfborder true
\pdf_colorlinks true
\pdf_backref false
\pdf_pdfusetitle true
\papersize a4paper
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation 0bp
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle fancy
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
שלום
\begin_inset Foot
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
שלום
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following code to Settings > LaTeX Preamble:

```
\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \kern -3pt
  \hbox to \textwidth{\hfill\vrule height 0.4pt width .4\textwidth}
  \kern 2.6pt
}}
```

You can of course change the dimension, but the total height of the construction must be 0pt. In the above example it is -3pt+0.4pt+2.6pt=0pt.

Comment: Thank you!! So if I want to make it little bit longer what should I write?

Comment: Change the length after `width` to for example `0.5\textwidth` or `10cm`.